# No gradient defined for operation tf.scatter_update

Tags: tensorflow, gradient

I use `tf.scatter_update` to update non-trainable variables `AL` and `AO` in my code. However, When I run the optimizer, `tf.train.AdamOptimizer(config.actor_lr0,0.9,0.999,1e-8).minimize(actor_loss)`, I am getting error `LookupError: No gradient defined for operation 'actor/encoder/beer_game_flow_8/next_scat_j_2' (op type: ScatterUpdate)`. 
I found that `tf.scatter_update` does not have gradient, and it is the reason that I am getting the error. 
The updates in the code are:

`self.players[k-1].AS = tf.scatter_update(self.players[k-1].AS, 
                    self.curTime + leadTimeIn, 
                    tf.add(self.players[k-1].AS[self.curTime + leadTimeIn], possible_shipment), name='next_scat_j'
                    )`

`self.players[k+1].AO = tf.scatter_update(self.players[k+1].AO, 
                    self.curTime + leadTime, tf.add(self.players[k+1].AO[self.curTime + leadTime], 
                    self.players[k].actionValue(self.curTime, self.playType))
                    , name='handle_scat_j')`

Since both `AS` and `AO` are non-trainable, I do not need their gradient and in this `op`, only these two variable exist. So, I was wondering why `TensorFlow` want to obtain the gradient, and is there any way that I could stop the AdamOptimizer to consider `scatter_update`?
I mean, can I exclude a given op in compute_gradient?
I appreciate any comments.

Thanks,
Afshin

Comment: Can you use tf.stop_gradient (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/stop_gradient)

Comment: No, it gives me error `'ScatterUpdate' Op requires that input 'ref' be a mutable tensor (e.g.: a tf.Variable)`.

Comment: @AfshinOroojlooy, I have the same problem, have you found a way to handle this error?

Comment: @DenisKuzin I could not find any easy approach. What I found is, you need to implement a gradient function for yourself, which cannot be done in few minutes. I changed the way that I was developing the algorithm, so no longer I need the `scatter_update`.